# How do I create a ClaimsPrincipal in my Blazor/.NetCore "Session"?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

**Background:** I have an old MVC app that I'm experimenting with migrating to a shiny new Blazor app. Blazor seems to tick a lot of boxes for me here. Wunderbar. For clarity this is the solution template in VS2022 where there's a WASM, a .Net Core host, and a shared project. I will have plenty of api calls that need to be secured as well as UI that will be affected by various authorization policies (eg show/hide admin features).

I have a table of users with an ID and hashed password.

I can't get Blazor to use its native authentication/authorization processes with my existing store.

My latest attempt was to create an AccountController on the server app (inherits ControllerBase) and put in a Login method that gets the username and password from a json body for the moment. I have successfully ported the old authentication mechanism and I have my user that I have verified the password for. I now want to use Claims and a ClaimsPrincipal to store some of the things about the user, nothing too complex.

**How do I** put my ClaimsPrincipal into the app such that the WASM UI can see it AND future calls to api controllers (or ControllerBase controllers) will see it?

I have found hundreds of examples that use built-in scaffolding that lets it use EF to create tables and things but I need to use my existing stores and I can't find anything that joins the dots on how to connect the WASM and the server side.

I have read about and implemented  and  around the place, and tried some @authorize around the place but my WASM just doesn't know about the authenticated user.

In my login controller I have attempted a bunch of different approaches:

1. I implemented a custom AuthenticationStateProvider, got it into the controller via DI, called the AuthenticationStateChanged() and for the lifecycle of that one controller call I can see my HttpContext.User gets the new identity. But the WASM doesn't, and if I hit the same method again the User is null again
2. I tried to implement a SignInManager. This never worked well and my reading suggests that it's not compatible
3. I discovered ControllerBase.SignIn() which hasn't helped either
4. HttpContext.SignInAsync() with Cookie authentication (because that was the example I found)
5. I tried setting HttpContext.User directly (and tried combining that one call with the AuthenticationStateProvider implementation simultaneously)

I tried creating a fresh solution from template to pick through it, but it would appear to be reliant on hacking up my EF DataContext. I just want to find how I tell the whole contraption "Here's a ClaimsPrincipal" and have that work in both the WASM and api controllers.

I'm also not excited to have a dependency on the Duende stuff - I don't see what it brings to the table. I don't really need a whole identity provider, I already have my own code for authorizing against the database I just need to get my very boring ClaimsPrincipal into my app.

Am I going at this all wrong? Has my many years of "old school" experience stopped me from seeing a modern way of doing this? Am I trying to force cool new stuff to behave like clunky old stuff? Yes I'd love to switch to Google/Facebook/Twitter/MS authorization but that's not an option, I have passwords in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom `AuthenticationHandler`.

Here's the relevant bits of one of mine (see credits at bottom for where I lifted some of the code).  You'll need to pick out the pieces from the code to make your work.  Ask if you have any specific problems.

The custom `AuthenticationHandler` looks up your user in your database and if authenticated, builds a standard `ClaimsPrincipal` object and adds it to the security header.  You can then use the standard Authorization and AuthenticationStateProvider.

```cs
public class AppAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AppAuthOptions>
{
    private const string AuthorizationHeaderName = "Authorization";
    private const string BasicSchemeName = "BlazrAuth";
    
    //this is my custom identity database
    private IIdentityService _identityService;

    public AppAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AppAuthOptions> options, IIdentityService identityService, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _identityService = identityService;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        // Check the Headers and make sure we have a valid set
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey(AuthorizationHeaderName))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No Authorization Header detected");

        if (!AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(Request.Headers[AuthorizationHeaderName], out AuthenticationHeaderValue? headerValue))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No Authorization Header detected");

        if (!BasicSchemeName.Equals(headerValue.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No Authorization Header detected");

        if (headerValue is null || headerValue.Parameter is null)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("No Token detected");

        // Get the User Guid from the security token
        var headerValueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(headerValue.Parameter);
        var userpasswordstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(headerValueBytes);

        // This will give you a string like this "me@you.com:password"
        if (youcantdecodethestring ))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Token submitted");

        // Get the user data from your database

        var principal = await this.GetUserAsync(userId);

        if (principal is null)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("User does not Exist");

        // Create and return an AuthenticationTicket
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }

    // method to get the user from the database and retuen a ClaimsPrincipal
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal?> GetUserAsync(Guid Id)
    {
        // Get the user object from the database
        var result = await _identityService.GetIdentityAsync(Id);
        
        // Construct a ClaimsPrincipal object if the have a valid user
        if (result.Success && result.Identity is not null)
            return new ClaimsPrincipal(result.Identity);

        // No user so return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can construct a `ClaimsIdentity` like this:

```cs
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, record.Id.ToString()),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, record.Name),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, record.Role)
}, "MyIdentityProvider");
```

```cs
public class AppAuthOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string Realm = "BlazrAuth";
}
```

The service registration:

```cs
public static class AuthServicesCollection
{
    public static void AddAppAuthServerServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication("BlazrAuth").AddScheme<AppAuthOptions, AppAuthenticationHandler>("BlazrAuth", null);

        services.AddScoped<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
    }
}
```

Credits: Some of this code was derived from: [https://harrison-technology.net/](https://harrison-technology.net/custom-authentication-handler-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks mate, that feels like a good push in the right direction but I've still got some gaps. Some of this will be because I've made a mess of trying things...

My WASM project won't start, it's complaining that the CascadingAuthorizationView can't find an AuthenticationStateProvider - I can make that go away by adding the call to AddApiAuthorization() but that creates other problems that only seem to solve by adding an OIDC controller that I don't want. What am I missing to make the this work? Currently my program.cs on the WASM only has the boilerplate with httpclient injected.

Comment: So to get it all running "happily" although not yet working - I've added a call to AddOidcAuthentication in my wasm's program.cs - there's no errors and my app is working as expected for non-authenticated users. I even see the handler above is getting called for each call. I still can't see how to actually take in my username and password though and get it to that handler please

Comment: Put in a break point after the yield and step though the handler.  At this point `var userpasswordstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(headerValueBytes);` check the contents of `userpasswordstring`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the if(youcantdecodethestring) and worked out how to read the details, but I can't work out how to set them in the first place. I have a login form with a LOGIN button, how do I get the user input into where this can see it?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't appear to have helped. I hard coded to `return AuthenticationResult.Success(ticket);` with a valid principal and that all looks good, except the CascadingAuthenticationState still shows the `NotAuthorized` sections. I still seem to be missing the connection between the server and the blazor view cleverness